# changing quote by time and on click

Tags: javascript, html

i made a quote generator it is changing by time but i want to be able to change it with a button click as well so i added a function but when i click it (on Codepen) İt says undefined...

```js
var text = ["Welcome", "Hi", "Sup dude", "Hola"];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
var inst = setInterval(change, 2000);

function change() {
  elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
  counter++;
  if (counter >= text.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
}

function newQuote(){
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (text.lenght));
  document.getElementById('changeText').innerHTML = text[randomNumber];
  
}
```

```html
<div id="changeText"></div>
<button onclick="newQuote()">new quote</button>
```

and I need to reset the change time after a click
for example, lets say the quote is changing every 20 seconds

CHANGED
20,19,18,17
CLICKED FOR NEW ONE
and now the timer should be 20 again shouldn't go like 17,16,15... it should be 20,19,18..

I don't know how to do that too... would be great if you guys can help.

Comment: Please post the fiddle link here, it will be easy to look into.

Comment: change text.lenght to text.length

Comment: Probably clearInteval(inst); inst = setInterval(change, 2000);

Comment: In `change()`, first: `clearInterval(inst);`, and at end: `inst = setInterval(change, 2000);`.
(You might want to explore calling `change()` and `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's a typo in `text.lenght` (should be length).
edit: first line in function newQuote()

Comment: yep typo fixed and now its working but i still need to figure out how to reset the timer after i hit the new quote button. https://codepen.io/magule-the-typescripter/pen/zYrXdeQ

Comment: You could stop and start it again, with clearInterval(inst) and then setInterval again

Comment: Use `clearInterval(inst);` in the `newQuote()` function.

Comment: @FurkanKalaycıoğlu there is a typo in the codepen. It is `clearInteval` instead of `clearInterval`. Also, you should use the `elem` variable instead of using `document.getElementById('changeText')` in the `newQuote` function.

Answer (score 0):

The button click results in `undefinde` because of a typo. You wrote `lenght` instead of `length`.